# Can I add parameters to the function defined in Delta Live Table

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a code which contains multiple functions written. And some function takes other function as parameter. And all these functions are called at the end in another function which is under try except block. Now I want to write my code in DLT way. Can anyone provide some examples of such scenario.

```
def funct(param1): x = ... ...... return x 
def funct2(funct(param1)): y = ..... ....... return y 
def all(): param1 = "something" ddd = funct(param1) vvv = funct2(ddd)
```

Comment: For Example:
    def funct(param1):
        x = ...
        ......
    return x
    
    def funct2(funct(param1)):
        y = .....
        .......
    return y
    
    def all():
       param1 = "something"
       ddd = funct(param1)
       vvv = funct2(ddd)

Comment: Provide your dlt code.

Comment: def dmc(mdl, chp):
    query = spark.sql('''select * from tbl1 where model = {mdl} and chapter = {chp}''')
    return query
 
def dcc(dmc):
 df = dmc.withColumn("trc", lit("Source"))
 return df
 
def main():
 dfs = dmc(mdl, chp)
 dcc(dfs)
 
mdls = ['111','222','333']
chps = ['22','23','24']

for am in mdls:
 print(am)
 mdl = am
 if(len(chps)>0):
  for ac in chps:
   chp = ac
   main()


THis is a small sample of the way code is written

Comment: You want this in dlt way?

Comment: yes, I want it in DLT

Comment: Anything on this ??

Comment: I think you need to write any one function with dlt decorator which returns your final df

Comment: Yeah, but I am also interating over multiple times. So how do I take care of iteration. If you can provide some insights or show me a dlt code for the given code

Comment: Any Clue you can suggest me ??

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any one of the below ways.
First, returning merged data based on models and chapter.

```
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

schema = StructType([
    StructField("mdls", StringType(), True),
    StructField("chps", StringType(), True)
    ])
    
mdls = ['111','222','333']
chps = ['22','23','24']
    
@dlt.table()
def data():
    cross_product = [(mdl, chp) for mdl in mdls for chp in chps]
    merged_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=schema)
    for mdl, chp in cross_product:
        query = f"select * from my_table where mdls = '{mdl}' and chps = '{chp}'"
        result = spark.sql(query)
        merged_df = merged_df.union(result)
    fdf = merged_df.withColumn("trc", lit("Source"))
    return fdf
```

And you will get output in single table filtering all those models and chapters.

[image]

Or if you want to use for loop for each delta live table you need to give different name each time.
you use below code.

```
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

def main(mdl,chp):
    @dlt.table(name=f"tbl_{mdl}_{chp}")
    def data():
        query = f"select * from my_table where mdls = '{mdl}' and chps = '{chp}'"
        result = spark.sql(query)
        fdf = result.withColumn("trc", lit("Source"))
        return fdf
        
mdls = ['111','222','333']
chps = ['22','23','24']

for mdl in mdls:
    print(mdl)
    if(len(chps)>0):
        for chp in chps:
            main(mdl,chp)
```

And you will get a tables for each model and chapter pairs like below.

[image]

Output:

[image]